# Documented bugs of Firefox/jQuery/CSS animations together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox, animation

I'm coding a website that uses jquery to switch CSS classes, these classes run CSS animations.

In Google Chrome and Internet Explorer 9/10 everything works perfectly, on Firefox (Aurora 24 and Firefox 23) animations are not performed, but the rest works.

So for example if I click a button which should hide a box and show another one, on Chrome the animation is performed with the smooth transition, on Firefox is performed without smooth transition.

The strange thing is that if I change the CSS value which should be animated, by console, the animation works.

The site has about 10 animations that run simultaneously, but just 5 works properly.
Trying to disable the last (and heavier) 3 animations fixs the problem. So maybe it's a kind of overload not properly managed by Firefox...?

I can't provide a JSFiddle because when I write one it works and so is impossible to show the problem...

This is the part of code that causes the problem:

```
console.log("3D Accelerated animation");        

console.log("oldpage = "+oldpage+"\npage = "+page+"\nnewpage = "+newpage);

if(oldpage != newpage) eoldpage.removeClass("active"); 
$(".slider > li").attr("style", "").removeClass("animation");

epage.css({"transform": "translate3d(0, 0, 0)"});

enewpage
.css({"transform": "translate3d(" + pagew * db + "px, 0, 0)"})
.addClass("active");

eboth.addClass("animation");

enewpage.children("section").load('/pages/' + newpage + ".php?lang=" + lang, function() {

    var hmorpher = enewpage.children().height();
    $("#heightmorpher").css({"height": hmorpher});
    $(".parallax").css({"height": Math.pow(hmorpher + 200, 600)});

    epage.css({"transform": "translate3d(" + (pagew * da * 2) +"px, 0px, 0px)"});
    enewpage.css({"transform": "translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)"});


    $("body").removeClass("active");

});
```

I know is not easy to understand without a working example.
In few words, the animation generated by this part of code is a kind of page slider, the current page slides on left or right (depending of the position in the menu respect to the new called page), and the new page slides at the same time from the opposite direction.
I use this plugin: https://github.com/zachstronaut/jquery-css-transform to animate transform on all browsers.

So I'm here just to ask if someone knows about a Firefox's bug with this behavior.

.

### Edit:

here a live demo of the page:
http://demo.mywebexpression.com/customers/pelplastic/

it's a bit buggy because I've exported it with the "Save page as...", by the way click on the **FIRST CLICK ME!!** menu entry, then try to switch between the two **CLICK ME** menu entries.

### For who talks about vendor prefixes:

This Fiddle shows you that Firefox supports the not-prefixed version, so the problem is not the vendor-prefix:

http://jsfiddle.net/3wM2V/1/

Comment: Rather than a jsfiddle, are you able to just put an example of the non-functioning page on a web server somewhere, or paste the HTML, JS, and CSS here in separate code boxes?

Comment: When I click on the things that you described on that page, I don't see even the partial animations that you describe.  Instead of putting something out there that's "a bit buggy", please put the full example of what is not working.  If "Save page as..." is causing it to be buggy, then don't use that feature.

Comment: just click on the *first click me!!!* tab and then use the two *click me* tabs, it works in Chrome and Explorer 10, but in Firefox the page-slide animation works only half way

Comment: The link you gave, http://demo.mywebexpression.com/customers/pelplastic/, is redirecting to http://demo.mywebexpression.com/home . There are no tabs on that page; there is only a list of what appear to be unstyled links.  You may need to clear your cache and correct the issue before the incorrect behavior can be observed.

Comment: the URL change is part of the website navigator, and if you don't refresh the page don't cause problems, why do u need to refresh the page? if you need that use the correct link.

Comment: I don't think that I made myself clear.  When I said "you", I meant "you", not me.  In order to try to achieve greater clarity, could you please verify that the image at the following link is what you see when you look at the page? [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/DCwi5Md)

Comment: Sorry there was a problem, now you should see it in the right way

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is your use of the CSS3 rule `-webkit-tranform` this only covers "webkit" browsers.

Instead you need to set all the browser specific rules:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);  /* Chrome, Safari 3.1+ */
-moz-transform:    translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);  /* Firefox 3.5-15 */
-ms-transform:     translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);  /* IE 9 */
-o-transform:      translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);  /* Opera 10.50-12.00 */ 
transform:         translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.10+ */
```

This site http://css3please.com/ will help a lot, it generates css3 with the browser specific names.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: No, I've said that if I change the value within the debug console the animation is performend, also Firefox supports transform without prefixes and by the way I'm using a jQuery plugin (I've said it in my question) which automatically adds vendor prefixes where needed.

Comment: Hi Fez, If I change the value from `-webkit-transform` to `-moz-transform` on the demo site you have linked it works in Firefox. Hence my suggestion, it doesn't appear your plugin is adding the correct rules.

Comment: Where did you added the `-moz-transform`? In my CSS there is only one `-webkit-transform` inside a `transition-property`, I've added also -`moz-transform` and it doesn't works.

Comment: on the `ul.slider li` I just replace the `-webkit-transform` that is there currently with the correct `-moz` prefixed rule.

Comment: `transition-property: -moz-transform,transform,left;` ? It doesn't work. And Firefox 23 supports the not-prefixed version. http://caniuse.com/#search=transform And by the way it wouldn't work editing the values within the debug console if the problem would be this.

Comment: Well `transform` is **not** being set, On Firefox 23 I see [-webkit-transform](http://imgur.com/BSFYdl1) instead of transform or -moz-transform - there's something wrong with your plugin...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37502/discussion-between-illizian-and-fez-vrasta)

Comment: Fez, I notice you're now adding the non-prefixed transform rule on that demo site - any chance this question can be accepted now? ;)

Comment: I've added them just to show how they don't make the thing works.